# Protect Single Page App with stand alone API from XSRF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application, csrf

I have two node servers, one is dedicated to serve the (frontend of my) single page of the app (developed in react), the other one is my backend API. I would like to protect my app from XSRF attack, so I tried to follow what is told in https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Nodejs_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-anti-csrf-tokens
But it seems this is a case where frontend and backend are under one single node server, how should we proceed in my case then ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look into [Refresh tokens](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/refresh-token-protection-implications.html) in that case, but this is just a tip.